# Rails/RoR - NoMethodError (undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, destroy

I have a TranslationsUser table and a FavoriteTranslation table. I want a TranslationsUser to only have one favorite translation, however I do not want to use validations because I want my controller to replace a favorite translation if one already exists. Instead, I created a `validate_uniqueness` function.

When I try to replace a TranslationsUser with a new favorite translation, I get the following error in my terminal:
`` NoMethodError (undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass): ``

I think the problem may be the `before action :set_favorite_translation` since it defines @favorite_translation

If so, how can I delete a specific FavoriteTranslation record: `transUser.favorite_translations.first`

If not, please help me figure out what the issue is! Many thanks.

---

```
    before_action :set_favorite_translation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


 def create

    transUser = TranslationsUser.find(favorite_translation_params[:translations_user_id])


    @favorite_translation = FavoriteTranslation.new(favorite_translation_params)
    @favorite_translation.user_id = @current_user.id

    if validate_uniqueness(transUser) == false
        transUser.favorite_translations.first.destroy
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @favorite_translation.save
        #format.html { redirect_to @favorite_translation, notice: 'Translations users comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @favorite_translation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

end

def validate_uniqueness(transUser)
      if FavoriteTranslation.joins(:translations_user).where('lang_id = ?', transUser.lang_id).where('favorite_translations.user_id = ?', @current_user.id).where('translations_users.translation_id = ?', transUser.translation_id).exists?
          return false
      else 
          return true
      end
 end

def destroy
    @favorite_translation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to favorite_translations_url, notice: 'Translation was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end


private
def set_favorite_translation
  @favorite_translation = FavoriteTranslation.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: use `has_one` relation and subsequently `update` the record

Comment: You can use `FavoriteTranslation.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_initialize`...But I personally feel validations should be at model level. Define a relation as quoted by @Nithin and use validate_uniqueness_of validation in model. In the controller just use first_or_initialize...

Comment: Is @current_user a TranslationUser or do you have a User model too?

Comment: I have a User model too. @current_user is the user that is logged in.

Comment: @Nithin had the right idea. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the given solutions, but I found that the following worked. Thanks for all the help!!!!

```
 def create
    transUser = TranslationsUser.find(favorite_translation_params[:translations_user_id])

    if validate_uniqueness(transUser) == true
        @favorite_translation = FavoriteTranslation.new(favorite_translation_params)
        @favorite_translation.user_id = @current_user.id
    else
        update
    end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @favorite_translation.save
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @favTrans.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def update
    transUser = TranslationsUser.find(favorite_translation_params[:translations_user_id])
    @favorite_translation = FavoriteTranslation.joins(:translations_user).where('lang_id = ?', transUser.lang_id).where('favorite_translations.user_id = ?', @current_user.id).where('translations_users.translation_id = ?', transUser.translation_id).first
    @favorite_translation.translations_user_id = favorite_translation_params[:translations_user_id]
    @favorite_translation.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @favorite_translation.update(favorite_translation_params)
        'Translations users comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @favorite_translation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are almost there. Just add the following inside the destroy method.

```
def destroy
    if @favorite_translation
      @favorite_translation.destroy
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to favorite_translations_url, notice: 'Translation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

This basically checks if the favorite_translation is present, else the translationUser don't have a favorite_translation and so will allow the new record to be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want validations, no worries, writing proper associations will help you and *DRY* up your code as well.

Firstly, use `has_one :favorite_translation` and `belongs_to :translations_user` associations, then in you `create` action..

```
def create

  transUser = TranslationsUser.find(favorite_translation_params[:translations_user_id])

  @favTrans = transUser.favorite_translation || transUser.build_favorite_translation

  @favTrans.assign_attributes(favorite_translation_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @favTrans.save
      format.html { redirect_to @favTrans, notice: 'Translations users comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @favTrans.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Now you don't need to `destroy` records and use `has_many` relations, create and update are kinda merged here.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery.min jquery_ujs)
```

from `application.rb` to resolve the issue.